# How should I programatically change content in a linked activity on button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This question may seem simple but please hear me out. I've made a huge mistake my project contains 300+ activities that are in a single storyboard and I've just recently figured out that Xcode is terrible at handling that. So what I would like to do is to have my different content which is now currently displayed in separate activities written into the code so that I only have to have the minimum amount of activities in my storyboard. This may be hard to follow I apologize.

In my head here is how it should work. I'l give an example.

In my app I have a section called MAPS, from the homepage you click on the maps button and it brings you to a menu which has buttons with the maps names on them. As you would expect the name of the map on the button brings you the the activity with said map. The problem is that each map is in a separate activity that is linked too inside the storyboard.

What I would like to do is programatically call each separate activity from within one activity in my storyboard effectively replacing 20+ activities with 1.

Here is what my map view controllers look like (they're actually .png images with a scrollview)

MapRoute1.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MapRoute1 : ViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

- (void)centerScrollViewContents;
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;

@end
```

MapRoute1.m

```
    #import "MapRoute1.h"

@interface MapRoute1 ()

@end

@implementation MapRoute1

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // 1
    CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

    // 2
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale * 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale);

    // 3
    CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    // 4
    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // Zoom out slightly, capping at the minimum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale / 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MAX(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale);
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:newZoomScale animated:YES];
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Return the view that you want to zoom
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // The scroll view has zoomed, so you need to re-center the contents
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // 1
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_route1.png"];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    // 2
    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;

    // 3
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:)];
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // 4
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;

    // 5
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.5f;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

    // 6
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

So as you can tell the only part that changes in each separate map is this line of code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_route1.png"];
```

What I would like to do is have some sort of list of all my images and when the button is clicked for that map(image) it will replace this line of code with the image name or Map that the button should link too. The overall code and everything should only be one activity in my storyboard that is linked to be each button in the MAPS menu.

Currently all activities are linked by a simple "control click-drag" in the storyboard and are contained inside of a navigation controller which provides back navigation.

I would like to keep the back navigation with the navigation controller but simply replace the image inside of the scrollview.

Thanks in advance!

-Derek

Comment: What do you mean by "activities"? Are you talking about the buttons' action methods? If the only thing that changes is the image name, then put all the image names in an array, and give all your buttons tags that correspond to the index in the array you want to access when you click the button.

Comment: Hey yes sorry I must have been confusing Android in with this. By activities I mean view controllers that are inside of my storyboard.

Comment: I think what I said in my first comment should work for you. Put all the image names in an array and give all the buttons tags, and use that tag (in a single IBAction for all the buttons) to access an element of the array. Pass that string to the next controller, then do a push to it (or use a push segue in the storyboard).

Comment: I have been trying to implement the method you stated I'm sure that it will work the only thing is that I'm a noob at arrays and persisting data to other VCs. Would you mind posting some sample code that covers how a button knows what text to send how to send the text and how to recieve the sting value into the [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]; for the map.